# Can I call .storyboard like .xib?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Is it possible to use `<name_of_storyboard>~iphone.storyboard` and `<name_of_storyboard>~ipad.storyboard` like we can use with .xib names?? Or do I have to use always something like `if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`to distinguish which storyboard I want to run?

Example:

Imagine I have this in my project Cell~iphone.xib and Cell~ipad.xib

I call `objCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];` and depending on the device, xcode will choose which .xib to run. (Ok no problem)

Now if I have MainStoryboard~iphone.storyboard and MainStoryboard~ipad.storyboard in my project and I want to call `UIStoryboard *storyBoard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];` does it work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try it, e.g. in the Simulator? Did it work or not?

Comment: No it didn't work. It seems that UIUserInterfaceIdiom is the only option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works.

You can do something like that in AppDelegate:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
   mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryIPHONE" bundle:nil];
} else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryIPAD" bundle:nil];
}
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: It was not that what I asked but thanks anyway :) I will use your way